# Can`t place on the X axis, dates from ms sql server

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
 $(function () {
 Highcharts.setOptions({ 
            global : { useUTC : false
            }
        });
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'coefficient 10 days',
        x: -20
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Company', 
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: { 
        categories: [<?php echo join($data, ',')?>], 
        type: 'datetime'

    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Коэффициент'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '', enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [ 
    {
        name: 'value',
        data: [<?php echo join($koef, ',')?>]
    }, {
        name: 'norm',
        data: [<?php echo join($norm, ',')?>], color: '#FF0000'
    }
    ]
});     
});
```

When format in php as 'Ymd', date is correct but as number, like '20151210' this not readable for users. When i try format (in php code) 'd.m.Y' java say script1007 error. On api.highcharts.com nothing in the description specified what to do. Probably i need set in javascript something about datetime setting.

Comment: my php code:   
$conn = <connection settings>
$sql="SELECT comp,cex, dates, kzf,'0.95' as norm FROM [test].[dbo].[History] where dates>((SELECT max(Dates) FROM History)-10) and comp='Company' and cex='itg' order by dates";
$zap = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $zap === false) {die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($zap)) {
$data[] = date_format($row["dates"],'d.m.Y');
$koef[] = $row["kzf"];
$norm[] = $row["norm"];
}

Comment: Highcharts take timestamps in milliseconds for datetime.

Comment: You have both categories, and a type:datetime declaration on your x axis.  It's either one or the other - not both.  Provide your date values -- in the form of millisecond epoch time stamp, or a Date.UTC object -- as the x values of your data array, and use the type:datetime property, without the categories.

Comment: I provided dates in my sql statement in the form of millisecond epoch time stamp. But x-axis give me numbers in epoch time stamp. I do not understand what I do at all. Can you give an example, how this work, please?

Comment: For now, how your json data looks like ?

Comment: In the x-axis: 1449360000,1449446400,1449532800,1449619200,1449705600,1449792000,1449878400,1449964800,1450051200,1450137600

Comment: Instead of categories use [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions)

Comment: If i enter static numbers in the script properties, everything is cool. But my data array from sql server, looks like: <?php echo join($data, ',')?>, and x-axis is null, after use tickPositions. I can`t understand how this php construction enter to highcharts

Comment: Maybe better is use json_encode and communicate php with javascirpt by ajax, instead of php injection.

Comment: Yes! With json it`s work! So thank you very much and my best regards) On x-axis use "categories: <?php echo $json_data?>" without "[]". In php use: "$data[] = date_format($row["dates"],'d.m.Y');" and "$json_data=json_encode($data); ". Without unix epoch time. My datetime is present as text format.